# Laravel hyperlink to a specific record from table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a table in my database, say `users` with one of the columns being `internal_id`. I have a a list of users being displayed in `view.blade.php`

Now suppose each user is a link which when clicked displays the details of that user and each user has a unique `internal_id`. I want this `internal_id` to be used when called for all the column details of the user clicked. How can I do this?

Comment: internal_id is your primary key. but where is your code ?

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create a route:

```
Route::get('user-profile/{internalId}', ['as' => 'profile', 'uses' => 'UserController@showProfile']);
```

Then you need to create a link. You can use simple URI:

```
{{ url('user-profile/'.$internalId) }}
```

Or you can use name of the route:

```
{{ route('profile', ['internalId' => $internalId]) }}
```

To get internal ID in a controller, do this:

```
public function showProfile($internalId)
{
    $profile = User::where('internal_id', $internalId)->first();
    ....
}
```

Comment: Yes how can you be so sure he is not using ajax or a modal to view details for user.

Comment: @Bugfixer in stead of downvoting ask OP what he thinks and make your answer or comment, it is not good to downvote for such reason.

Comment: you are right but let him show what he tried and what help needed.